# delete/dispose only particular cell in DataGridView c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, imagelist

I'm new to c# programming (more exactly, new to just programming),
 and am having trouble creating windows forms application using the Visual Studio 2019 Community version.

I want to create a list of selectable images. (Like the image below)

[Like this image, and wanna delete only 'these'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7dNT.png)

I tried to use Listview with ImageList component, but it was hard to make each items **selectable**. (Selectable means, when I select the image or images, backcolor of it/them changed, such like cells in a DataGridView).

So I tried to make it with imageCells in DataGridView like the code below.

```
for (int j = 0; j < rowCellCount; j++)
{
    DataGridViewImageColumn imgCol = new DataGridViewImageColumn();

    imgCol.HeaderText = "" + j;
    imgCol.Width = 61;
    imgCol.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Zoom;

    dgvImage.Columns.Insert(j, imgCol);
}
```

It was 'almost' good, except for one problem: cannot delete cells whose value is null.
Is there any way to delete particular cells in datagridview, not all cells in row?

I searched several times, but I couldn't find the answer....

Comment: sorry for not mentioned this: the code what I showed is just a little part of whole code.

Comment: Add one more line to your code: `imgCol.Style.NullValue = new Bitmap(1, 1);` and try.

Comment: Thanks JQSOFT! I think your suggestion is enough to solved my problem.